# NULL safe NOT LIKE operation in mysql

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have InnoDB table with two columns (1) account(int) (2) comment(varchar).

I have index on `(account,comment)`

Now I want to run query like

`select * from table where account = 1111 AND comment NOT LIKE 'abcd%';`

**How can i make the `NOT LIKE` null safe?**

I mean, include all records whose `comment` not starts with 'abcd', even if its null value.

Comment: You may: use additional `OR comment IS NULL`; mask NULL using `IFNULL(comment, '')` or `COALESCE(comment, '')`.

Comment: thanks @Akina I used this trick. getting correct result. One doubt, Would it be able to use the index `(account,comment)` for performance?

Comment: What trick? I post 2 different variants. And when the output is compact (low records count) whereas the source table records count is huge, the best way is third one - use UNION ALL, first subquery as your query above, second with IS NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql > create table nsnl(a varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql > insert into nsnl values (null), ('asdf');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql > select * from nsnl;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
| NULL |
| asdf |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql > select * from nsnl where a not like 'as%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql > select * from nsnl where a not like 'as%' or a is null;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And that's how you can easily find that out yourself. Plus, when you do it yourself, you memorize it better. At least that works for me.

Comment: Thanks @tombom. One doubt thought... `where a not like 'as%' or a is null`  will it hit any performance impact in case there are lot of rows...

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing your data. Just try it out. `not like` is generally not handled well by indexes, you might not notice it though.

Comment: *not like is generally not handled well by indexes* That's not right when substitution sign `%` is posessed at the end of pattern.